# Nuke ChannelMask_Knob required argument

Tags: python, nuke

I am trying to figure out what the required string argument for the nuke.ChannelMask_Knob() function corresponds to. On some other knob constructors the first argument seems to be the name/label, but that does not seem to be the case for the ChannelMask_Knob...

I have looked at the Nuke Python API, but I am unsure how to follow it back to the appropriate function definition to answer my question. My line of thinking is that this has to do with the **init** function which is overridden by the ChannelMask_Knob class, but the parameter list according to the API is just "..." which I believe means it has to do with a builtin function. Since I can't see the body of the **init** function, I have no idea what that argument is used for, thus my problem...

Here is an example of my issue:

```
test_knob = nuke.ChannelMask_Knob("required_argument")
node.addKnob(test_knob)
```

This works just fine, but I would like to know what the "required_argument" is used for since it is apparently not the name or label for the knob.

Answer (score 1):

You must intentionally leave a blank space for parameter in `ChannelMask_Knob('')` method. It doesn't work. But for assigning a `name` and a `label` you need to use `.setName('name')` and `.setLabel('label')` methods respectively. It works fine.

Here is a code:

```
import nuke

noop = nuke.nodes.NoOp()
### maskKnob = nuke.ChannelMask_Knob('name', 'label', False)
maskKnob = nuke.ChannelMask_Knob('')
maskKnob.setName('name')
maskKnob.setLabel('label')
noop.addKnob(maskKnob)
```

For selection of channel in this dropdown menu it's better to use the following method:

```
nuke.selectedNode().knob('name').setValue('alpha')
nuke.selectedNode().knob('name').setValue('disparity')
```